# xcodeでGitHubにPushしたいのですが、No remotes availableとなっています。

Tags: xcode, github

【やりたいこと】
xcodeのプロジェクトをGitHubにPushし、他のパソコンでも同じプロジェクトを使えるようにしたい。
【経過】
ネット上の「XcodeからgitとGitHubを使う方法・基本編」「今日からはじめるGitHub 〜 初心者がGitをインストールして、プルリクできるようになるまでを解説」 を参考に、GitHubへのSSH接続を確認するまではできました。
【問題点】
xcodeでcommitやbranchはできるのですが、Pushができません。
xcodeのmenu＞sourceControl>pushと進んで、Pushのところを開けてもPushLocalChangeの下がNo remotes availableとなっていて、選択できません。
【やったこと】
・ネットで探しましたが、解決できません。（xcodeのmenu＞sourceControl>でプロジェクトが出るという記事がありましたが、ここにプロジェクトは出てこないのです。）
・Xcodeのメニューから> Preferences> Source Controlと開いてGitを確認すると自分の名前とメアドが入っています。
・cloneが作れるのではないかと思い、GitHubでプロジェクトのURLをコピーし、それをxcodeのSource Control>cloneで開いてみましたが、「reference 'refs/heads/master' not found (-9)」とエラーでした。

【環境】
MacBookAir Sierra10.12.6　xcode9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushするには、Remotesに何か（通常はorigin）を設定する必要があります。
　左上の左から２番目のアイコンを選択して、branchやtagやremoteの管理ツリーを開き、remoteをcontrol+クリックして、「Create "xxx" Remote on GitHub...」か「Add Existing Remote...」で設定してください。
[image: Remotesの場所]

参考：[[iOS 11] Xcode 9で“だいぶまとも”に！新機能をまとめてみた](https://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/iphone/xcode-9-new-features/#toc-github)

Comment: 了解しました。諦め掛けていましたが、うまく行きました。xcodeでプロジェクトを共有できるようになりました。感激です。ご教示に感謝します。